# Глобальный запрет ввода определенного символа во всех формах

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Как реализовать Запрет ввода во всех формах определенного символа?
У меня в решение более 100 форм с разными TextBox и RichTextbox.
Хочу запретить ввод «'» символа во всех формах, не реализуя в каждой форме событие keypress..

Comment: Создайте свой текстбокс и используйте везде его

Comment: А для чего вам это и что вы считаете вводом? Вставка из буфера обмена - тоже ввод и при том не по-символьный, в отличие от ввода с клавиатуры. Напишите функцию, которая будет проверять содержимое контролов ввода, обнаруживать запрещенные символы и информировать пользователя об этом, ну или моча менять их на допустимые или просто удалять. Подцепите ее в обработчиках нужных контролов. Это будет куда понятнее и надежнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте регулярку

```
string text="";
Regex checkRegex = new Regex("[']");
if (!checkRegex.IsMatch(text))
{

}
```